# Elevation of 3D function

Tags: calculus, functions, 3d

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x^2/y & y \neq 0 \\ 0 & y = 0\end{cases}$

I need to draw the elevation (or you may call it Equivalent curve) of this function and I don't know how to draw them. Can some-one help me please? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2%2Fy%2Cy)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know how to draw only the elevation curves, on a paper and without help from wolframalpha :)
I think "elevation" is not correct word in calculus, do you have another word for that?

Comment: Do you mean the contour map?

Comment: @ozo -yes, I think that this is the word I was looking for. Thanks again. English isn't my native lang'. So, would you like to help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $f(x,y)=k$ for some constant $k$ then $y=\frac{1}{k}x^2$. In other words the contour lines (the lines with constant $f$ values) will consist of a series of quadratic curves emanating from the origin in both the positive-$y$ and negative-$y$ directions.

Begin with $k=\pm1$ and so draw $y=\pm x^2$. And then consider $k=\pm 2$ and you know this is equal to the curves you've already drawn but divided by 2, and so on for increasing $k$. Like this:

[image]

Comment: First - thanks. But I didn't understood the last sentence you wrote, and how to draw them.

Comment: @momd I have updated my answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: so everytime I just need to put y=k (const) in the function and then changing (increasing) its value? 'till which number?

Comment: @momd That's right (although I assume you mean $f=k$ (const)). And you keep going until you feel you've done enough to make the structure clear - I wouldn't go beyond $k=\pm 5$.

Comment: OK, i got it. but now, what the lines are actually presenting?

Comment: @momd The value of $f$ is constant along each curve. So along the blue curves $f(x,y)=\pm 1$, along the green curves $f(x,y)=\pm 2$, etc. Therefore, as $k$ increases (i.e. as the consecutive curves approach the $x$ axis) the $z=f(x,y)$ component moves further out of the plane.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. In simple words - I'm asking - what is the point of this? How it "help" me or what it "gives" me?

Comment: @momd Well why do we use contour maps at all? Answer: It reveals three-dimensional structure in a two-dimensional drawing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line